# Visible UITableViewCells not resizing on rotate

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cells. When I rotate the device, the visible cells do not resize. Scrolling to new cells works fine and when I scroll back, all is well, but is there a way to get the initial, visible cells to smoothly resize on rotate?

`[self.tableview reloadData]` from the UITableViewController; works, but I don't think that is the optimal solution, as it requires a network call for data retrieval.

I am already calling the following code from the UITableViewController in order to layout some gradient layers I use, but this does nothing to resize the ImageView.

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    for (ProjectCell *cell in [[self.tableView.subviews firstObject] subviews]) {
        cell.laidOut = NO;
        [cell layoutSubviews];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

As long as the cells you want to reload are the visible cells.

Comment: Thanks.  This gives me an error as typed above, but if i use [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] instead of [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows, nil], for some reason the error goes away.  Thanks for the solution.

Comment: great, answer is fixed