# TableViewCell not resizing after reloading rows at visible paths

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom tableViewCell that I would like to resize when the view rotates. I took a look at this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640964/visible-uitableviewcells-not-resizing-on-rotate), as it addresses the same exact issue, but for some reason it is not working for me.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)


        //start visible row updates
        self.instructionsTableView.beginUpdates()
        //reload rows that are at the "visible" indexPaths
        self.instructionsTableView.reloadRows(at: self.instructionsTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .automatic)
        self.instructionsTableView.endUpdates()

    }
```

Comment: How should the cell be resized and what is happening currently?

Comment: The "number of visible rows" is almost certainly going to change during rotation... Much easier to simply call `.reloadData()` (as it only re-inits / re-draws the visible rows to begin with).

Comment: `reloadData()` is not a good implementation, as it is rather expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `animateAlongsideTransition` in the coordinator to pass an empty animation block and a completion block, moving your update code into the completion block so that it fires after the transition is finished. You don't even need the reloadRows as the begin/endUpdates will recalculate the heights.

Comment: I implemented this suggestion. removing the call to reload data does not work. However, putting `beginUpdates`,`reloadData()`,`endUpdates` in the completion block worked, but the screen update is very slow. Is there anyway way to the resizing of the cell up?

Comment: Do you mind explaining how to use the animation block?

Comment: The animation block is used to do any transition animations that you want to occur alongside the system-provided transition animation. Doing so avoids glitchy animations. But in your case, the result you're trying for is dependent on the final state of the transition, so it's done in the completion block after the transition completes.

Comment: If you use `reloadData` in the completion handler, don't wrap it in `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates`.

Comment: I figured using reload data was a bit expensive, would you say that is a better alternative to this?

Comment: If your cells just need to resize, then `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` should cause the cell heights to be recalculated. If that doesn't achieve your desired end, then `self.instructionsTableView.reloadRows(at: self.instructionsTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .automatic)` is less expensive than `reloadData`.

Comment: Good deal, I will stick with the `self.instructionsTableView.reloadRows(at: self.instructionsTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .automatic)` then. Thank you so much.